# How to get the highest test score per individual, per test when there are multiple administrations?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 10 different State tests a student can take. A student can take each of those 10 multiple times. What I want is to pull the highest score that a student achieved on each of the 10 tests.

I tried the code below and it's not working. It's just returning dozens of records of the same score for the same student and same test. I wish there was a way to group by student.number and exam, but whenever I try to group by exam it tells me it's not a valid variable. I've tried to put the case when into a subquery and then apply the group by to an outer query and it still didn't work. Not sure where to go from here...

```
    select STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_ID
       ,max(studenttestscore.numscore) OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENT_NUMBER,TEST.NAME)

                               
,case when test.name like '%Global%' Then 'Global History'
              when test.name like '%Earth%' then 'Earth Science'
              when test.name like '%Physics%' then 'Physics'
              when test.name like '%Chemistry%' then 'Chemistry'
              when test.name like '%Algebra I%' then 'Algebra I'
              when test.name like '%Algebra II%' then 'Algebra II'
              when test.name like '%Living%' then 'Living Environment'
              when test.name like '%Geometry%' then 'Geometry'
              when test.name like '%English%' then 'ELA'
              when test.name like '%U.S%' then 'US History'
         end as exam 
         
          ,test.name
         
 from STUDENTS STUDENTS

INNER JOIN STUDENTTEST STUDENTTEST ON
STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID                       
INNER JOIN TEST TEST ON
TEST.ID=STUDENTTEST.TESTID
INNER JOIN STUDENTTESTSCORE ON 
STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID and STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID
```

I've also tried the below just to get the score for a single test (global history). All this does is return the highest score a student has ever achieved.

```
select STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as GLOBALSID
       -
        ,max(STUDENTTESTSCORE.NUMSCORE) as MAXGLOBALScore
 from STUDENTS STUDENTS

INNER JOIN STUDENTTEST STUDENTTEST ON
STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID                       
INNER JOIN TEST TEST ON
TEST.ID=STUDENTTEST.TESTID
INNER JOIN STUDENTTESTSCORE ON 
STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID and STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID
                       
 where 
test.name like '%Global%'

group by student_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to achieve this by mean of RANK() function. Actually if you use windows function for aggregation, it does not reduce the number of records like it happens with GROUP BY clause.

Hope this SQL helps to solve your problem -

```
Select student_id, numscore, exam, name
From (select STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_ID
       ,studenttestscore.numscore as numscore
       , rank() over (partition by STUDENT_NUMBER,TEST.NAME order by studenttestscore.numscore desc) rrank
       ,case when test.name like '%Global%' Then 'Global History'
              when test.name like '%Earth%' then 'Earth Science'
              when test.name like '%Physics%' then 'Physics'
              when test.name like '%Chemistry%' then 'Chemistry'
              when test.name like '%Algebra I%' then 'Algebra I'
              when test.name like '%Algebra II%' then 'Algebra II'
              when test.name like '%Living%' then 'Living Environment'
              when test.name like '%Geometry%' then 'Geometry'
              when test.name like '%English%' then 'ELA'
              when test.name like '%U.S%' then 'US History'
         end as exam 
         
          ,test.name as name
         
 from STUDENTS STUDENTS

INNER JOIN STUDENTTEST STUDENTTEST ON
STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID                       
INNER JOIN TEST TEST ON
TEST.ID=STUDENTTEST.TESTID
INNER JOIN STUDENTTESTSCORE ON 
STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID=STUDENTTEST.STUDENTID and STUDENTS.ID=STUDENTTESTSCORE.STUDENTID)
Where rrank = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to group the results but maybe you haven't applied GROUP BY in quite the right place. ["Analytic functions are the last set of operations performed in a query except for the final ORDER BY clause."](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) So you can't simply add a GROUP BY to the end of your existing query.

I've tried grouping in the query below and also added a column alias for the max score. Does my example differ from the way you did your grouping?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            students.student_number AS student_id,
            MAX(studenttestscore.numscore) OVER(
                PARTITION BY student_number, test.name
            ) AS MAX_SCORE,
            CASE
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Global%' THEN 'Global History'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Earth%' THEN 'Earth Science'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Physics%' THEN 'Physics'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Chemistry%' THEN 'Chemistry'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Algebra I%' THEN 'Algebra I'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Algebra II%' THEN 'Algebra II'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Living%' then 'Living Environment'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%Geometry%' THEN 'Geometry'
                WHEN test.name LIKE '%English%' THEN 'ELA'
                WHEN test.name like '%U.S%' THEN 'US History'
            END AS exam,
            test.name
        FROM
            students      students
            INNER JOIN studenttest studenttest ON students.id = studenttest.studentid
            INNER JOIN test        test ON test.id = studenttest.testid
            INNER JOIN studenttestscore ON studenttestscore.studentid = studenttest.studentid
                                        AND students.id = studenttestscore.studentid
    )
GROUP BY
    student_id, MAX_SCORE exam, name;
```

Comment: This will not work. Code has some glitch here `GROUP BY
    student_id, MAX_SCORE exam, name;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need simple `group by` as follows:

```
select STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER as STUDENT_ID
       ,max(studenttestscore.numscore) as max_mark
       ,<your_case_statement>
       ,test.name
  From students      students
       INNER JOIN studenttest studenttest ON students.id = studenttest.studentid
       INNER JOIN test        test ON test.id = studenttest.testid
       INNER JOIN studenttestscore ON studenttestscore.studentid = studenttest.studentid
                  AND students.id = studenttestscore.studentid
Group by STUDENTS.STUDENT_NUMBER, test.name
```